# Python Seaborn stacked barplot multiple columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

[image: data frame trying to graph using seaborn barplot]

I'm trying to plot the dataframe above using Seaborn barplot.

```
plt.figure()
sns.set_theme(context = "notebook", style = "darkgrid", palette = "deep", font = "sans-serif",
              rc = {"figure.figsize": (20, 12)})

ax = sns.barplot(data = graph_df, x = "Month", y = "Contract", color = "green")
ax = sns.barplot(data = graph_df, x = "Month", y = "Definite", color = "lightgreen")
ax = sns.barplot(data = graph_df, x = "Month", y = "T1", color = "blue")
ax = sns.barplot(data = graph_df, x = "Month", y = "T2", color = "lightblue")
ax = sns.barplot(data = graph_df, x = "Month", y = "CXLD", color = "red")
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tick.FuncFormatter(reformat_large_tick_values))
plt.ylabel = "Total Rent"

plt.show()
```

The plot that is produced doesn't show all the values for each month. For instance, look at February, it should have Contract = 404,600 (green), Definite = 94,450 (light green), T1 = 726,000 (blue) and T2 = 121,850 (light blue) for a total of $1,346,900. But, it only shows the blue (T1) and light blue (T2) values and the y axis should be capable of showing that value.

[image]

I used matplotlib to create the same graph and this shows how the graph should look. The only reason I'm not using this, is I can't seem to get the y axis to convert to normal dollar values and the y axis label to show the value for "Total $'s".

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data? (not in an image please).

Comment: Seaborn doesn't support stacked bar plots. Note that `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(...)` is a pure matplotlib function, not depending on seaborn.  You can do the same with a bar stacked plot, which you could create via pandas' plot interface. Just like seaborn, pandas also returns the `ax` on which the plot was created.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me get the result I wanted.

Comment: The question was misunderstood and wrongly closed, as the author clearly asks for a "seaborn solution". This was not supported before, but now possible with the recent seaborn.object API. See https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Bar.html#seaborn.objects.Bar. Or try this code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
df.head()

so.Plot(df, x="pclass", color="sex").add(
    so.Bar(), 
    so.Count(), 
    #so.Dodge()
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating stacked plots is usually easier in pandas/matplotlib. I have given the code for this below...

```
colors = ['green', 'lightgreen', 'blue', 'lightblue', 'red'] ## Colors for the bars
graph_df.set_index('Month').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, color=colors) ## Plot
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', useOffset=False, axis='y') ## No offset
plt.gca().set_ylabel("Total $'s") ## Set Y-axis
```

[image]